Communication between Python and HTML
I have an HTML page and a Python program locally, and I have calculated some results on the Python program. How can I transfer these results to the HTML page? I cannot find suitable code to communicate between the HTML page and this Python program
What I want is not for the HTML page to frequently initiate requests and then have Python process the requests and transmit the data. What I want is to establish a long connection, and as soon as Python calculates the result, it will be immediately transmitted to the HTML page. I have tried using the websocket library, but Python's websocket library is asynchronous. I don't want asynchronous transmission, I want synchronous transmission. Asynchronous transmission will cause the order of transmitted data to be chaotic

If possible, could you please teach me how to make Python's websocket synchronous instead of asynchronous

This code sends a message every 1 second and does not use asyncio:
import websockets.sync.server
import time

def handler(websocket):
    x = 0
    while True:
        websocket.send(f"Hello, {x}!")
        x += 1
        time.sleep(1)


with websockets.sync.server.serve(handler, host="", port=1234) as server:
    server.serve_forever()

